# Skype Video Call URI

Tags: ios, skype

I am working on a simple app that initiates Skype calls.

It successfully initiates Skype audio call using apple's URI scheme

```
[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:skype_id?call"]).
```

But when I try to make a video call using

```
[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:skype_id?call&video=true"]
```

it still initiates audio call and launches Skype but nothing happens after that (no audio call or video call is made). I have seen some posts where people mentioned that they used similar URI for making video calls for Skype in iOS that worked fine before but now it doesn't work.

I should mention that Android version of the app our team is working on have no such issue. It successfully starts making video call using same URI.

Is this a problem of latest version of skype developed for iOS?

Comment: Im actually having a similar issue on android. it makes the audio call successfully, but video is not enabled by default.

Comment: yes,we tested the android version of this app with previous version of Skype in android. Problem started with the latest version released by Skype for both Android and iOS.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and it's making me crazy.

Seems to be an issue with the latest version of Skype for iOS...

http://community.skype.com/t5/iOS-iPhone-and-iPad/Url-for-skype-video-call-from-ios-is-not-working-on-ver-4-6/m-p/2052949

Comment: Hello Samin, Have you find any way for Skype URIs video calling ? Yet we have facing this issue.. please help us if you got any way for video calling. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello Mohit, Sorry, no luck yet. I am starting to believe that Microsoft has limited this api support and we may never be able to initiate direct video call in future via Skype.

Comment: Its good news that now Android version of Skype is able to make video call via URI scheme from another app but it became worse for iOS. URL Scheme is there but it doesn't do anything except initiating skype. Does anyone know any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

this seems to be totally bust in skype for iOS.
even skype://username?call comes up with a fairly unintuitive modal saying "Placing call with..." which does NOTHING unless you click "Voice Call"
All works fine in other systmes / browsers (windows, mac osx, android), though https is bust in chrome. which is just dandy.

maybe https://stackoverflow.com/users/1383154/allen-smith or someone from skypes side can comment??

according to http://handleopenurl.com/scheme/skype you can use skype://username?chat in an html link. Now that *sort of* works - as in it opens skype, but still doesnt initiate the call.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use the &video=true - IOS doesn't like it. Just use the ?call and it will work the same way it should (as if you appended the &video=true to it) and place a video call if video is available.

The skype stuff is pretty flaky - and my only success has been to use the skype buttons (using the skype-uri.js file and associated javascript for creating the buttons under HTTP (NOT HTTPS). HTTPS tends to break things in Chrome, and a few others.

What I did was sniff for IOS and remove the video=true accordingly so it works fine for all the other browsers too. End of the day, Skype really needs to clean up their act.